# Azure Active Directory App Manifest: getting 'Failed to update manifest: ObjectConflict'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to update an existing Azure app but unable to save and the website throws an error 'Failed to update manifest: ObjectConflict'
[image]

I'm updating the field called 'identifierUris'. It's a list and there is one element already and I'm trying to add another there.

Can't seem to find what this error is about. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Can you add additional details about what property you are trying to change?

Comment: I added the detail

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely you are trying to add a value to `identifierUris` which is already present in another app. Each value in `identifierUris` must be unique to a single Application object in Azure AD.

To check if it's already present on an app in your tenant, you can use [Azure AD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) to do a simple search to see if that's the case:

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'http:/example.com/id-uri')"
```

You could also do the query using the [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) (and signing in with your Azure AD account):

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications?$filter=identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'http:/example.com/id-uri')
```

Comment: I ran the command and there is another application that uses it

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "identifierUris/any(c:c eq 'https://onestore.microsoft.com')
>> "

ObjectId                             AppId                                DisplayName
--------                             -----                                -----------
ddabd3cf-ec29-45de-be56-fcf58878bcc6 0550bd23-95a6-49c0-b8ec-30158a939dae cr-poc

Comment: I'm following this doc and it says to add that URL to identifierUris https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service

Comment: In one tenant, only one application can have a given identifier URI.

Comment: Hey Philippe, according to this Microsoft doc I should be able to add onto identifierUris https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service

Comment: You can have multiple values in `identifierUris`, but only one app can have any given value at the same time. Someone else in your organization has already registered an app with the value you're trying to use, which is why you aren't allowed to.

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this when writing some samples.  The other answer is correct that there is another app that has already defined those identifierURI's under your AAD tenant.  But it only needs to be defined under one app.  You can create another app / client ID in AAD under the tenant that doesn't have the identifierURI's the docs say you need and it will work to get the right token / Store ID.

I did this with my sample where another client had already defined them and hit this error.  I just went ahead anyways with the rest of the setup docs and got it working requesting the right authorization / bearer tokens.  Just know that for the commerce ones, I had to re-publish my app to the store before I started to see results otherwise I was just seeing blank results.